# How can I get all database table names in Moodle using API

Tags: java, php, moodle

I need list of the database tables used by Moodle.

How can I get it ? Is there any API for that either in Java or PHP ?

I checked - APIs like - Data definition API, Data Manipulation API , Web Services but I could not find what I require.

These API help getting data from Moodle, but I need MetaData.

Please help. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this in Moodle

```
$tables = $DB->get_tables();
```

also

```
foreach ($tables as $table) {
    $columns = $DB->get_columns();
    foreach ($columns as $column) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Or use the information_schema

```
SELECT table_name
FROM information_schema.tables
WHERE table_schema = 'yourmoodledatabasename'
```